# Apollo GraphQL Schema Stitching issue with Resolvers when using Typescript

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

### Context

I am using the schema stitching (as demonstrated [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/graphql-apollo-server-tutorial/#schema-stitching-technical-separation)) in a typescript express app.

### Issue

Creating resolvers in different files seems to create build issues. However, creating resolvers in `app.ts` (as shown below) is fine.

#### Directory Structure

```
app
├── app.ts
├── resolvers
│   ├── graphql-user-resolver.ts
│   └── index.ts
└── schema
    ├── graphql-user-schema.ts
    └── index.ts
```

#### app/app.ts

```
import express = require('express');
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import schema from './schema';

const app: express.Application = express();

import resolvers from './resolvers';

const server: ApolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers,
});

server.applyMiddleware({app, path: '/graphql'});
app.listen({port: 8000}, () => {
  console.log('http://localhost:8000/graphql');
});
```

#### app/resolvers/graphql-user-resolver.ts

```
export default {
  Query: {
    me: () => {
      return {
        username: 'username',
      };
    },

  },
};
```

#### app/resolvers/index.ts

```
import graphqlUserResolver from './graphql-user-resolver';

export default [
  graphqlUserResolver,
];
```

### Build issue

```
app/app.ts:11:3 - error TS2322: Type '{ Query: { me: () => { username: string; }; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'IResolvers<any, any>'.
  Index signature is missing in type '{ Query: { me: () => { username: string; }; }; }[]'.

11   resolvers,
     ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/types.d.ts:31:5
    31     resolvers?: IResolvers;
           ~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'resolvers' which is declared here on type 'ApolloServerExpressConfig'


Found 1 error.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! server@0.0.1 tsc: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@0.0.1 tsc script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/.../.npm/_logs/2019-06-24T02_05_04_497Z-debug.log
```

---

### Defining `resolvers` in `app.ts` works fine:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    me: () => {
      return {
        username: 'username',
      };
    },
  },
};

const server: ApolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript is irrelevant here. Either use JS spread or write into an Object separately. Like:

```
export default x;

queries['Type'] = x;
```